# Outlook Addin to redirect email on an ad-hoc basis

Tags: microsoft-outlook, redirection, outlook-addin

I would like to redirect certain emails to a different email address when I desire, preferably by some kind of Addin button.

I know that I can create rules to redirect emails however there is no consistent rule I can apply.

Is there any way I can do this? It must be redirect and not forward as the redirected email will populate fields in FoGBugz and I want those fields to be those of the original sender.

Comment: Did you find something? I would love to have this functionality, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent "how to" on Aaron Lerch's blog [here](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/10/24/how-to-easily-redirect-an-email-thread-in-outlook/) for adding a macro to outlook that I believe has the functionality you want. I use the macro and it works well.

Comment: That is essentially a forward with some other fields filled in, which won't fix the OP's problem as far as I can tell, which would actually require spoofing the redirected email to appear to have come from the original sender.

Comment: @AdamV; the way I read the question is that @MrEdmundo is looking at a "consistent way" to redirect mail. The macro will work with Fogbugz for populating fields from the original sender.